# Python ldap3 thumbnailphoto from Active Directory

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, ldap

Python novice. So I am getting some attributes from acitve directory using python ldap3 and saving in a mysql database - all works fine.
I also get the thumbnailphoto attribute from the AD and save as a blob on the same mysql db table.

Here's the issue, I need it in a base64 type text but it seems to be returned in some other text format. [sample type text from ldap / mysql](https://pastebin.com/FAsUYhDc)

I believe it should be saved in base64 already ([base64 result required](https://pastebin.com/mTa4gKXr)) on active directory but thats not the case.

How can I convert this text returned from AD via ldap3 to base64 and save to the mysql database?

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb

startTime = datetime.now()

# ######################
# LDAP Setup
# ######################

serverName = 'ip'
domainName = 'xyz'
userName = 'xyz'
password = 'xyz'
base = 'base'

# ######################
# MySQL Connection Setup
# ######################
connsql = MySQLdb.connect(host = "ip",
                               user = "xyz",
                               passwd = "xyz",
                               db = "db",
                               port=3306
                               )

# ######################
# Main Code
# ######################

server = Server(serverName)
conn = Connection(server, read_only=True, user='{0}\\{1}'.format(domainName, userName), password=password, auto_bind=True)
conn.search(base, '(objectclass=person)', attributes=['sAMAccountName', 'displayName', 'mail', 'telephoneNumber', 'mobile', 'ipPhone', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'thumbnailPhoto'])
cursor = connsql.cursor ()

for i in conn.entries:
    cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO fwad
                (sAMAccountName, displayName, mail, telephoneNumber, mobile, ipPhone, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, thumbnailPhoto)
            VALUES
                (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                displayName = VALUES(displayName),
                mail = VALUES(mail),
                telephoneNumber = VALUES(telephoneNumber),
                mobile = VALUES(mobile),
                ipPhone = VALUES(ipPhone),
                physicalDeliveryOfficeName = VALUES(physicalDeliveryOfficeName),
                thumbnailPhoto = VALUES(thumbnailPhoto);
                """,(i.sAMAccountName, i.displayName, i.mail, i.telephoneNumber, i.mobile, i.ipPhone, i.physicalDeliveryOfficeName, i.thumbnailPhoto))   

connsql.commit()
cursor .close()
connsql.close()
print ("AD has taken ", datetime.now() - startTime, " on ", datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understand your question right, you can probably resolve your problem with this:

```
import base64
...
...
imgstring = conn.response[0].get('attributes', {}).get('thumbnailPhoto', '')
img_string_decoded = base64.encodebytes(imgstring).decode('utf-8')
```